# Fresh install of emacs 24.5.1 and Prelude not working because melpa wont download on OS X 10.11.2

Tags: package-repositories, prelude

I have a fresh install of Emacs 24.5.1 on OS X 10.11.2 and when I install prelude (https://github.com/bbatsov/prelude) via the recommended auto-magic way (curl -L https://git.io/epre | sh) then open emacs I get an error:

```
Warning (initialization): An error occurred while loading `/Users/caseyallred/.emacs.d/init.el':

error: Package `anzu-' is unavailable

To ensure normal operation, you should investigate and remove the
cause of the error in your initialization file.  Start Emacs with
the `--debug-init' option to view a complete error backtrace.
```

If i then run `M-x list-packages` it says that it `` Failed to download `melpa` archive ``

I'm a bit of Emacs noob and I have no idea how to fix it.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Melpa archive is fixed now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems that it's not a problem of your install but an issue on the Melpa side.
I've tracked the issue down as far as that the file "archive-contents" that Emacs tries to download from Melpa is currently corrupt / truncated:

http://melpa.org/packages/archive-contents

Guess we'll have to wait until the Melpa guys do something about it.

Answer (score 4):

MELPA is apparently having [issues](https://github.com/melpa/melpa/issues/3833) at the moment.